# Why decode does not working properly on Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, decode

Why I can `decode` this `%7B%22q%22:null` on web javascript and I cant do it on nodejs?

If I decode this on javascript web I get this result: `'{"q":null'`
  but when I do it on node I get this `¨"q":null`

How can I decode this on nodejs right?

My code:

```
 console.log(decodeURIComponent(`%7B%22q%22:null`))
```

Obs: Im using node on `v12.13.0`

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Post the code you use to decode the input text.

Comment: @axiac posted, I use decodeURIComponent, it works on browser but do not work on node

Comment: It works fine on Node.js v8.17

Comment: Lol, do you know how can I fix it on node 12v ?

Comment: It works fine on Node 12 too. I just tested with v12.14

Comment: It looks like a character encoding issue but `7B` is an ASCII character, it is never encoded on more than 1 byte. Is that the entire string you decode? Maybe the problem is somewhere around it.

Comment: Yes, its on this 7B, its the entity string. Im sure that my node is on 12.13.0 and its decoding `{`as `¨`I dont know why.

Comment: $ *node*
`Welcome to Node.js v12.13.0.
Type ".help" for more information.`
> `decodeURIComponent('%7B%22q%22:null')`
`'{"q":null'`

Comment: Lol it was a bug on Visual Code studio on console. Sorry guys, I didnt know. I run this command on console and it works fine.

Comment: On what OS? I just run it on Visual Studio console on macOS, with Node 8 and Node 12 and it worked as expected.

Comment: @axiac macOS Sierra 10.12.6 . Lol, I run on terminal and it works fine while I run on visual studio and It does not work.